# Grails 1.3.7 picks wrong view for controller

Tags: grails, view

I have controller named LoginController with action auth:

```
class LoginController {
   def auth = {
      render view: 'auth'
   }
}
```

So I go to the URL http://localhost:8080/myapp/login/auth, and want to see my view '/login/auth.gsp'. But I get the following error:

```
type Status report
message /myapp/WEB-INF/grails-app/views/jobSearch/auth.jsp
description The requested resource (/myapp/WEB-INF/grails-app/views/jobSearch/auth.jsp) is not available.
```

Seems that grails resolves wrong view name for some reason. Do you know, what's going on?

```
class UrlMappings { 
    static mappings = { 
        "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{ 
            constraints { // apply constraints here } 
        } 
        "/"(view:"/index") "500"(view:'/error') 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running `grails clean`? Your code looks OK.

Comment: No any changes in URLMappings
Sometimes grails clean helps. sometimes not.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @omarello, something looks like its mapping the login controller URL to 'jobsearch'. The error message relating to JSP is what happens when it can't find a matching gsp page and tries to fallback to JSP.

Comment: I have no standard grails UrlMappings, with bo special customization. This problem repeats with other controllers to. Sometimes it can be fixed by grails clean and restart.

Comment: Do you have jobSearch controller in your project?

Comment: Can you add your UrlMappings.groovy to the question?

Comment: <!-- language: groovy -->
    class UrlMappings {
        static mappings = {
            "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
     constraints {
        // apply constraints here
            }
        }
        "/"(view:"/index")
     "500"(view:'/error')
        }
    }

Comment: Can you add login.gsp to the question too? Maybe something is causing a redirect...

Comment: Otherwise all I can suggest is trying to turn on some of Grails' view resolution logging or do some debugging.